# My req.body for any parameters in my Express app are returning as undefined

Tags: node.js, express, request, undefined

So I have tried for DAYS now to request data from an input using req.body and np matter what I do I keep getting the data as undefined> I am using Express

Ive tried adding body parser but that also makes no difference

I am using express on a remote server accessing via putty and WinScp
I have checked the paramaters are corrrect so many times and literally spent days on this somebody please help!

This is my express app.js file

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');



var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

This is the post method I am using in the index.js

```
});router.post('/regnew', function(req, res, next) {
var username = req.body.username;
var email = req.body.email;
var password = req.body.password;

console.log("username" + username);

  res.render('registration');
});
```

Comment: YOu need to have body-parser installed. Install it and require it in your file. https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/body-parser

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I actually installed and required it and still get undefined

Comment: Are you able to hit the endpoint only when it is being triggered in the UI?

Comment: sorry I dont quite know what you mean by that

Comment: When does the console.log get printed? As soon as you start the node server?

Comment: sorry no only when i do that post request and it prints as undefined. I have the same problem all the time I had it set up to save to a mysqp table and the values all saved as null so it must just be something critical to actually pick up on the data because whevever I enter the info in the input it just wont translate

Comment: Did you import body-parser into the router file?

Comment: Do you mean the main js file? but yes I have                                                                            var bodyParser = require('body-parser');     at the top of both

Comment: Are you sending the same variables in the request body from the ui?

Comment: Yes 100% have chacked this so many times I so stuck at what the problem is have been on this issue for days and tried so many things

Comment: Your code looks syntatically correct. Not sure. If you can post a github link, I can have a look at it

Comment: Hi sorry about the delay if youre able to check it still that would be amazing https://github.com/Tarpe-Diem/danu7_tc3

Comment: If you're talking about the registration form provided on your Github, none of them have the name attribute, it's required so the parameters are filled by the request.

Comment: THANK YOU!!  I thought id would work so just to be clear every get request uses name and not ID>

Comment: Thank you so much to you both I cant believe it is something so trivial I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submitting traditional forms, the 'name' attribute must be set so the server-side code can identify the values being sent, otherwise, all inputs will be undefined/null/void.